# Is ContentFlow the only option for a library that support not only images but divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coverflow

I am trying to create a coverflow effect with a list of images and styled divs.

The only library out there that seem to support anything other that images is http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/ but it's a bit unmaintained and I am having problems with setting some properties for the non-image elements.

Is it the only library out there with such capability?

Isn't there anything jQuery based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 that may work for you:

[Roundabout](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout)

[Coverscroll](http://slobodan.99k.org/plugins/coverscroll.html)